# TemplateSyntaxError at /: Cannot Parse the remainder

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to update my homepage whenever a new "article" is added, however it is giving me this error whenever I try to update the page using my `updateHomepage` view it doesn't work and I get the error

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /
Could not parse the remainder: ' 'update_homepage'' from 'url 'update_homepage''
```

I am very new to django so any help with this would be amazing.

**My Views.py**

```py
def index(request):
    articles = Article.objects.all()
    context = {'articles': articles}
    return render(request, 'able/homepage.html', context)

def updateHomepage(request, pk):
    form = EditorForm(instance=task)
    context = {'form': form}
    article = Editor.objects.get(id=pk)
    return render(request, 'able/update_homepage.html', context)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditorForm(request.POST, instance=task)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect('/')

def editorview(request):
    editor = EditorForm
    context = {'editor': editor}
    return render(request, 'able/editor.html', context)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditorForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect('/')
```

**urls.py**

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='homepage'),
    path('editor/', views.editorview),
    path('update_homepage/<str:pk>/', views.updateHomepage, name='update_homepage')
]
```

**homepage.html**

```
    <h1>My Blog</h1>
{% for article in articles %}
    <div class="article">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h1>{{ article.title }}</h1>
        <h3>{{ article.text }}</h3>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
<a href="{{ url 'update_homepage'}}">Update</a>
```

**update_homepage.html**

```
<h3>Update Homepage</h3>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form}}
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: You write `"{{ url 'update_homepage'}}"` Note the `{{` and `}}`  are used to render a variable in the template while you want to use the `url` template tag. template tags are denoted by `{%` and `%}` so you should write `"{% url 'update_homepage' %}"`

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I tried it, it gave me a different error: `Reverse for 'update_homepage' with no arguments not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['editor/update_homepage/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/$', 'update_homepage/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/$']` I have no idea what this is